# Only half of screen height in VBox seamless mode on secondary screen

Tags: virtualbox, multiple-monitors

On my secondary screen my Windows 7 guest in Virtual Box works fine in Fullscreen but not in Seamless Mode.

In Seamless Mode the guest only gets half of the actual screen height (2048 x 723 px²)

Seemless on the first monitor works fine, the resolution is the right one.

Did anybody encounter the same issue? Is there a solution?

Thx a bunch.

Comment: I'm only seeing the left half of the (right-extended) second screen, on the right half of the second monitor, in fullscreen mode in my Windows VM after upgrading host Ubuntu & VirtualBox. It appears that, in fullscreen mode (for me), the second screen's coordinates are getting shifted right once correctly (by the common width of my monitors, or half the virtual desktop width), but also additionally once incorrectly, by half of a single monitor width. Not sure if this is a new bug, a bug fix with no migration of config settings, a migration error in my vbox config file, or something else.

Answer (score 0):

Execute these commands:

```
$ kill -15 $(ps aux | grep "VBoxClient --draganddrop" | grep "Sl" | awk '{print $2;}')
$ /usr/bin/VBoxClient --draganddrop
```

[Source](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/16296)